# Delete data from arcgiscache directory in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, cache

I have some ArcGIS cached layer on ArcGIS Server.
After deleting the service from ArcGIS manager, I expected that folder to auto-delete from directory arcgiscache, but it doesn't. In result I don't have a service, but do have arcgiscache.
I used REST clear cache but it did not help.
So how can I delete arcgiscache and service from ArcGIS Server correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are tools in ArcGIS Desktop to handle that.  On Esri's ArcGIS Server documentation page [Delete a Service](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/deleting-a-service.htm) it says:

> If you delete a cached service, the cache tiles, tiling scheme, and
> folder structure are retained on disk. If you want to delete the cache
> completely, use the [Delete Map Server Cache](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/server-toolbox/delete-map-server-cache.htm) tool. If you want to
> delete the tiles but leave the cache folder structure and tiling
> scheme, use the [Manage Map Server Cache Tiles](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/server-toolbox/manage-map-server-cache-tiles.htm) tool and set Update Mode
> to Delete_Tiles.

Comment: Yes, i saw it. But after this article https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013238 i don't understand what i should do.

Comment: @GRM What version of ArcGIS Server are you running?  That tech article is old (for 10.1-10.4) and talks about manually deleting the cache.  You now have tools (as per my answer) that will delete for you.  What are you stuck with?